# JPA oneToOne sql code generated differs from server to server

Tags: mysql, jpa, eclipselink, glassfish-4.1

I have a OneToOne relationship between 2 entities:

```
     @OneToOne(mappedBy = "parent")
     private Child child;


    @OneToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    @JoinColumn( name = "child_id", referencedColumnName = "child_id", insertable = false, updatable = false)
    private Parent parent;
```

At some point child_id = null was inserted into the parent table.  So data fetched from the child table should use null to find matching rows (wrong, but it should use it). Out of 3 dev environments with the same null insertions, one failed during searches for this data.  When I turned on sql logging for all environments:

```
<property name="eclipselink.logging.level.sql" value="FINE"/>
```

I saw this output for the actual db queries:

**sql exceptions in dev1 environment**

SELECT child_id, community_id FROM child WHERE (child_id = ?)
    bind => [**0**]]]

**no exceptions in dev2 environment**

SELECT child_id, community_id FROM child WHERE (child_id = ?)
    bind => [**null**]]]

in dev1 something is turning the nulls in the generated sql to zeros.  Same servers and versions, same application deployed, same database configuration, same eclipselink libraries (AFAIK) in both environments.  Any ideas why this is happening?

Glassfish4, JPA2.1, Eclipselink2.3

Comment: Your child_id mapping - you must have more then one to the field, as what you've shown wouldn't work otherwise. Chances are it is non-deterministically picking either an int type mapping or the null relationship when populating the value from the entity.   You would have to show the entity and the query if you need to fix this.

Comment: make your comment an answer, I haven't tested it yet, but I do indeed have a duplicate field - one is mapped, the other is not.